# Separator line between items in ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, .net-4.0

I like to put separator line between items in ListBox control . With that separator line I want to make the ListBox look a like table with one column and many rows.

Comment: [see this question i think it is same][1] and please provide the coding by which we can go through it 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747011/how-to-show-a-divider-between-items-in-a-listbox

Comment: I tried with ItemTemplate, but id doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic approach would be to define a CSS style for the list box items:

```
<style type='text/css'>
option { border-top: solid 1px gray; }
</style>

...

<asp:ListBox ...></asp:ListBox>
```

This will add a gray border at the bottom of each listbox-element.

Note: this will apply to all listboxes on that page. If you need that style only for certain listboxes, then apply a CSS class to the listbox and change the CSS to apply only to those:

```
<style type='text/css'>
select.table option { border-top: solid 1px gray; }
</style>

...

<asp:ListBox CssClass="table" ...></asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="0,10,0,10" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Name="title"/>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=Location}" Name="location"/>
                            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Width="48" Height="48" Source="ApplicationIcon.jpg"/>
                        </Grid>
           </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

set property `MultiColumn=true` and then:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[]
    {
        "Item 1, column 1",
        "Item 2, column 1",
        "Item 3, column 1",
        "Item 4, column 1",
        "Item 5, column 1",
        "Item 1, column 2",
        "Item 2, column 2",
        "Item 3, column 2"
   });
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Got inspired by NestorArturo and found out about the Border control.

It is very easy to wrap your ItemTemplate content in a Border control and specify the BorderThickness and BorderBrush. I went this way, because it doesn't require changes to my Grid in the ItemTemplate.

The Border control is described here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Border-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1-.aspx.

Comment: add it by css then 

cssclass_for_items{
border-bottom:1px solid urfavrt color;
}